# How to compare negative values with awk command in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

```
#!bin/bash

d1=-7
d2=-2

if (( $(awk 'BEGIN {print ("'$d1'" >= "'$d2'")}') )); then
    echo "yes"
    echo "$d1 >= $d2"
else
    echo "no"
fi
```

Why do I got?

```
yes
-7 >= -2
```

Thank

Comment: Why using `Awk` when you can use the arithmetic operator itself?, `if (( d1 >= d2 )); then`

Comment: because I also need to compare floating number.

Comment: You should add that info to the question

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply use shell variables by using `$variable_name` in `awk`. You should initialize an `awk` variable eg--> `-v var="$shell_variable"` then you could make use of shell variable's values in `awk` code. Try following `awk`:

```
awk -v d1="$d1" -v d2="$d2" 'BEGIN{if(d1>=d2){print "yes";} else {print "no"}}'
```

Comment: actually you can concatenate shell variables in a `awk` one-liner  - as long as you set the quotes right (compare numbers - not strings). `-v` is preferable because more readable though, and would he have used it he probably would not have run into the problem in the 1st place.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shorter command using `bc -l` to compare floating point numbers:

```
[[ $(bc -l <<< "$d1 >= $d2") -eq 1 ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```

Comment: This is cute approach

Answer (score 1):

The double quotes cause `awk` to perform string comparison, and `-7` is *lexicographically* greater than `-2`, since `7` comes after `2`.

You simply need to invert the single and double quotes so that the double quotes are used by the shell when expanding the variables. That is, instead of

```
if (( $(awk 'BEGIN {print ("'$d1'" >= "'$d2'")}') )); then
```

use

```
if (( $(awk 'BEGIN {print ('"$d1"' >= '"$d2"')}') )); then
```

However, passing the values into proper `awk` variables with the `-v` option is still a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

No need to do any additional numerical calculation in shell, just let awk set the appropriate exit status and test it with a simple shell `if`:

```
$ cat tst.sh
d1=$1
d2=$2

if $( awk -v d1="$d1" -v d2="$d2" 'BEGIN{exit (d1 >= d2 ? 0 : 1)}' ); then
    echo "yes"
    echo "$d1 >= $d2"
else
    echo "no"
fi

$ ./tst.sh -0.5 -0.409
no

$ ./tst.sh -0.5 -0.500
yes
-0.5 >= -0.500

$ ./tst.sh -0.5 -0.501
yes
-0.5 >= -0.501
```

Comment: As simple as that. ++

Answer (score 0):

Use **just** `bash`:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

d1=-7
d2=-2

if (( d1 >= d2 )); then
   echo "yes"
else
   echo "no"
fi
```

For floats:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

d1=-7.6
d2=-2.3

if [ "$(echo ${d1}'>='${d2} | bc -l)" = "1" ]; then
   echo "yes"
else
   echo "no"
fi
```

Comment: How can I do with for floating number?

Comment: Thank you very much klashxx